# How to extract data from mongodb (find and delete)

Tags: mongodb

Several computing server wants to receive command information from mongodb.

In order to prevent two servers from receiving the same command, I need to find a command for `find and delete`

How can I extract document from the collection?

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB there is a command [db.collection.findOneAndDelete()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/) that lets you get the deleted document

```
db.collection.findOneAndDelete(
   <filter>,
   {
     projection: <document>,
     sort: <document>,
     maxTimeMS: <number>,
     collation: <document>
   }
)
```

Comment: Does it prevent 2 servers from taking the same document?

Comment: @AntonioSEO I'm not sure about that, but i guess it does. This will work for sure if there is some time between 2 requests to MongoDB (so the first server deletes document before the second even finds it). That will be most frequent case, cause there is always a difference in time between any request made even from 1 machine based on million factors like network, number of requests your server and database compute at the moment, etc.